# Can't import plugin for lib

Tags: javascript, animation, pixi.js, spine

I try to import 'pixi-spine' plugin to my file where I imported PIXI lib. But I can't do it. I use webpack to package files. I try another variants to do it, but I have this error

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import {Spine} from 'pixi-spine';

import * as spineJSON1 from '../../../../../src/theme/assets/spine/ship_1_col_1.json';

export function newAnimations() {

  const app = new PIXI.Application();
  document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// load spine data
  app.loader
    .add('ship_1_col_1', spineJSON1)
    // .add('ship_1_col_1', 'src/theme/assets/spine/ship_1_col_1.json')
    .load(onAssetsLoaded);

  app.stage.interactive = true;
  app.stage.buttonMode  = true;

  function onAssetsLoaded(loader, res) {
    const ship_1_col_1 = new PIXI.spine.Spine(res.ship_1_col_1.spineData);

    // set current skin
    ship_1_col_1.skeleton.setSkinByName('ship_1_col_1');
    ship_1_col_1.skeleton.setSlotsToSetupPose();

    // set the position
    ship_1_col_1.x = 400;
    ship_1_col_1.y = 600;

    ship_1_col_1.scale.set(1.5);

    // play animation
    ship_1_col_1.state.setAnimation(0, 'idle', true);

    app.stage.addChild(ship_1_col_1);

    app.stage.on('pointertap', () => {
      // change current skin
      const currentSkinName = goblin.skeleton.skin.name;
      const newSkinName     = (currentSkinName === 'goblin' ? 'goblingirl' : 'goblin');
      ship_1_col_1.skeleton.setSkinByName(newSkinName);
      ship_1_col_1.skeleton.setSlotsToSetupPose();
    });
  }
}
```

But I have error from 'pixi-spine' - PIXI is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version 5, PixiJS no longer provides `PIXI` in the global namespace.

From the [v5 migration guide](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/wiki/v5-Migration-Guide#webpack):

> [With] [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and 3rd-party plugins, like
>   **pixi-spine**, you might have difficulties building the global `PIXI` object resulting in a runtime error `ReferenceError: PIXI is not
>   defined`. Usually this can be resolved by using [Webpack shimming
>   globals](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#shimming-globals).
>
> For instance, here's your import code:
>
> ```
> import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
> import 'pixi-spine'; // or other plugins that need global 'PIXI' to be defined first
> ```
>
> Add a `plugins` section to your **webpack.config.js** to let know
>   Webpack that the global `PIXI` variable make reference to `pixi.js`
>   module. For instance:
>
> ```
> const webpack = require('webpack');
>
> module.exports = {
>     entry: '...',
>     output: {
>         ...
>     },
>     plugins: [
>      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
>        PIXI: 'pixi.js'
>      }) ] }
> ```